# Desactivar validación de elementos especificos en un Wizard

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, formularios, validación, wizard

estoy creando un wizard que posee login y registro. Necesito desactivar las validaciones de ciertos input de mi formulario para poder continuar. Es decir, en este momento, si presiono login, se ocultan los elementos del registro y por ende necesito que se desactiven la validación de campos por completar y así al contrario, presiono registrar se ocultan los elementos del login y deberían desactivarse aquellas validaciones, para que cuando haga submit no me de error de "faltan campos por completar". Estoy utilizando la libreria jquery.smartWizard.min.js

Mis funciones ocultar y mostrar

```
function registrate(){

$('#registro_nombre').removeClass('d-none');
$('#registro_apellido').removeClass('d-none');
$('#registro_correo').removeClass('d-none');
$('#registro_password').removeClass('d-none');
$('#registro_confirmacion').removeClass('d-none');

$('#login_correo').addClass('d-none');
$('#login_contraseña').addClass('d-none');


 }

function sesion(){

 $('#registro_nombre').addClass('d-none');
 $('#registro_apellido').addClass('d-none');
 $('#registro_correo').addClass('d-none');
 $('#registro_password').addClass('d-none');
 $('#registro_confirmacion').addClass('d-none');

 $('#login_correo').removeClass('d-none');
 $('#login_contraseña').removeClass('d-none');

}
```

Este el step de mi wizard

```
<div id="step-5">
     <div id="form-step-4" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
                                       
        <div class="form-group" id="login_correo">
          <label >Correo electrónico</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-rounded" name="email" required>
       <div class="help-block with-errors" style="color:red"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group" id="login_contraseña">
       <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
       <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-rounded" name="password"required>
      <div class="help-block with-errors" style="color:red"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group d-none" id="registro_nombre">
      <label for="email">Nombres</label>
      <input id="name_modal2" type="text" class="form-control form-control-rounded" name="nombres" required>
      <div class="help-block with-errors" style="color:red"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group d-none" id="registro_apellido">
      <label for="email">Apellidos</label>
      <input id="segundo_nombre_modal2" type="text" class="form-control form-control-rounded" name="apellidos" required>
      <div class="help-block with-errors" style="color:red"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group d-none" id="registro_correo">
     <label for="email">Correo electrónico</label>
     <input id="email_modal2" type="email" class="form-control form-control-rounded" name="email" required>
     <div class="help-block with-errors" style="color:red"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group d-none" id="registro_password">
     <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
     <input id="password_modal2" type="password" class="form-control form-control-rounded" name="password" required>
     <div class="help-block with-errors" style="color:red"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group d-none" id="registro_confirmacion">
     <label for="repassword">Confirmar contraseña</label>
     <input id="password-confirm_modal2" type="password" class="form-control form-control-rounded" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
    <div class="help-block with-errors" style="color:red"></div>
    </div>
   <button class="btn" onclick="sesion()">Inicia sesión.</a>
   <button class="btn" onclick="registrate()">Registrate aquí.</a>
  <button id="inicio" class="mt-4 btn col-12 btn-rounded d-block d-lg-inline-block mb-1" style="background:#F2790F;color:white">Guardar publicación</button>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Este es la validación del wizard

```
$("#smartwizard").on("leaveStep", function(e, anchorObject, stepNumber, stepDirection) {
    var elmForm = $("#form-step-" + stepNumber);
    // stepDirection === 'forward' :- this condition allows to do the form validation
    // only on forward navigation, that makes easy navigation on backwards still do the validation when going Route::
    if (stepDirection === 'forward' && elmForm) {
        elmForm.validator('validate');
        var elmErr = elmForm.children('.has-error');
        if (elmErr && elmErr.length > 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Intenta asignando el atributo _required_ solo a los elementos visibles.

Comment: O podrías controlar la validación en un archivo externo del backend, para que no dependas de los `required` del lado del cliente.